# Azure Devops: installing a Windows Service

Tags: azure, windows-services, azure-pipelines

I am trying to automate installing windows service using Azure DevOps pipeline. I installed Windows Service Manager from here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MDSolutions.WindowsServiceManagerWindowsServiceManager and added it to the pipeline as a task. The windows service should be installed on the virtual machine where the pipeline is, so I provided "LocalSystem" as Run As Username, and nothing for password. The service was not installed with the following error:
Service ' (MyServiceName)' cannot be created due to the following error: The account name is invalid or does not exist, or the password is invalid for the account name specified

I tried also the credentials I use to get to the virtual machine, but it gave the same error. How can this be solved?
Added:
The service can be installed without problems using installutil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Azure Devops: installing a Windows Service

You could try to use [deployment groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops) to test, if you are using the private agent:

[image]

As the [document](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MDSolutions.WindowsServiceManagerWindowsServiceManager&ssr=false#overview) state:

> **Service Name** - The name of the Windows Service installed on the Deployment Group Target.

You could also refer to the [similar thread](https://github.com/Dejulia489/WindowsServiceManager/issues/54) for some more details.